# Adding packages in netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, import

I have a file in Java that was given to me that I am trying to edit, however when I hit build in netbeans, I get the errors below. It worked fine until I made the changes. I'm not sure why the jar file would work before, and yet now I can't build it. I'm a noob... How do I get these packages? Thanks.

---

```
C:\Users\Hendrick Brutsaert\Desktop\scrapers\Investing (1)\Investing\src\investing\InvesterMain.java:15: error: package org.jsoup does not exist
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
C:\Users\Hendrick Brutsaert\Desktop\scrapers\Investing (1)\Investing\src\investing\InvesterMain.java:16: error: package org.jsoup.nodes does not exist
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
C:\Users\Hendrick Brutsaert\Desktop\scrapers\Investing (1)\Investing\src\investing\InvesterMain.java:17: error: package org.jsoup.nodes does not exist
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
C:\Users\Hendrick Brutsaert\Desktop\scrapers\Investing (1)\Investing\src\investing\InvesterMain.java:18: error: package org.jsoup.select does not exist
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
C:\Users\Hendrick Brutsaert\Desktop\scrapers\Investing (1)\Investing\src\investing\InvesterMain.java:19: error: package org.openqa.selenium does not exist
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
C:\Users\Hendrick Brutsaert\Desktop\scrapers\Investing (1)\Investing\src\investing\InvesterMain.java:20: error: package org.openqa.selenium does not exist
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
C:\Users\Hendrick Brutsaert\Desktop\scrapers\Investing (1)\Investing\src\investing\InvesterMain.java:21: error: package org.openqa.selenium does not exist
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
C:\Users\Hendrick Brutsaert\Desktop\scrapers\Investing (1)\Investing\src\investing\InvesterMain.java:22: error: package org.openqa.selenium does not exist
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
C:\Users\Hendrick Brutsaert\Desktop\scrapers\Investing (1)\Investing\src\investing\InvesterMain.java:23: error: package org.openqa.selenium.chrome does not exist
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
C:\Users\Hendrick Brutsaert\Desktop\scrapers\Investing (1)\Investing\src\investing\InvesterMain.java:24: error: package org.openqa.selenium.interactions does not exist
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like path for the `jsoup.jar` and `selenium.jar` is not located correctly.
First download jsoup.jar from [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjsoup160jar.htm) and selenium.jar from [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/s/Downloadseleniumjava230jar.htm) and add them to libraries of your project.

in netbeans in project window Expand your project and right click on libraries ans select add jar/folder and locate your `jsoup.jar` and `selenium.jar` file locations and Add them. Then build the project.

Answer (score 0):

You are supposed to include the third party dependency jars in your project.

https://jsoup.org/download
http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/

You can download them from here.
Edit your project properties, go to library and add these jars. Should do it.